# How to refer to a value in the root store from a store of a module?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

How to refer to a value in the root store from a store of a module?

Somehow like this:

the root store (store.js):

```
import myModule from './myModule.js';

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        someValue: 'Cool stuff'
    },
    modules: {myModule}
});

export default store;
```

and the module (myModule.js):

```
import store from './store';  // doesn't work - here get "undefined"

export default {
    state: {
        arrayOfStuffs: [ store.state.someValue ] // <<-----
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the structure of your codes please? Are the store.js at the same level as myModule.js?

Comment: @KienHaTrung That's right, they are at the same level